# OS X terminal eating the shift key

Tags: macos, tmux, terminal.app

I'm switching from iTerm 2 to the stock OS X 10.8.5 terminal (work policy, iTerm isn't on the approved software list). In my tmux configuration, I've mapped shift-left and shift-right to change windows. This worked in iTerm 2, but not in Terminal.app.

In vim (where I've mapped the naked left and right arrows to do something similar, with vim tabs), it acts as if I am pressing the arrow keys, unmodified.

Answer (score 6):

It took some playing around, and googling, but these settings enabled me to use control-arrow and shift-arrow for navigating tmux panes and windows (respectively)

[image: Terminal-> preferences->any profile-> keyboard tab]

The action is *send text*, here is a small list of what they mean:

**\33** is an escape sequence
**[1;2** is shift
**[1;5** is control
**A** is up arrow
**B** is down arrow
**C** is right arrow
**D** is left arrow